# Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

im creating a simple app for android using Google Maps v2.

I think i did something wrong in getting the api-key ...

I followed the tutorial "http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/"

It worked properly, but in my case the map doesnt show up (...)

I created a package like "com.mycustommap" and added on Api Console "key;com.mycustommap" is that right?

Also im running it on a Galaxy Note 2 and creating the project on Eclipse.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you would need to show us the code

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on Windows go to

`C:\Users\YOUR_USER\` directory, hold down the `Shift` key, right click on the `.android` folder and select `Open command window here`

Then type `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore`, hit enter when asked for password and copy your SHA1 fingerprint.

Then open your browser to `https://code.google.com/apis/console/` go to `API access` and click on `Create new Android key`

Then enter there `SHA1_KEY;com.mycustommap` you should enter something like
`45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example`

Your package name should match what you have in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mycustommap"      <==  YOUR PACKAGE NAME
  ...
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you must have th following

```
<permission
    android:name="com.mycustommap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.mycustommap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
        ...
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
   ....
</application>
```

Where your `YOUR_API_KEY_HERE` is the key you copy from the Google APIs Console.